# Scrolling switch buttons groupe

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tying to achieve this kind of switches :

[image]

A groupe of bootstrap buttons(or switches) that can scrolls-x when the number of buttons(switches) is more then 3.

I've tryied several solutions but what I get is this:

[image]

when I add `overflow: hidden` to the parent and `overflow-x: scroll` to the shild div.

I'm using **[these toggle switches](http://codepen.io/zerubeus/pen/bBeGWQ)** .

Any hints on how to achive this will be much apreciated.

Comment: `overflow: hidden`

Comment: Try mixing `display: inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap`.

Comment: doesn't work :/, seems like there is no solution for this ...